# Maui Shell Navigating from a single page to tab pages causes 'Relative routing to shell elements is currently not supported'

Tags: shell, navigation, maui

```
<Shell
    x:Class="MyApp.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views">

    <ShellContent Route="login" FlyoutItemIsVisible="False" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:LoginPage}" />

    <ShellContent Route="products" Title="Products" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ProductsPage}" />

    <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Product">
            <ShellContent Route="product" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ProductPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Details">
            <ShellContent Route="details" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ProductDetailsPage}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

*ProductsPage* lists products. When I click on a product I would like to navigate to *ProductPage*, which shows two tabs to navigate between *ProductPage* and *ProductDetailsPage*.

Within the *ProductsPage*'s viewmodel I'm calling `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"product?id={product.Id}")`. This raises `Relative routing to shell elements is currently not supported. Try prefixing your uri with ///: ///product`.

If I instead call `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///product?id={product.Id}")` as suggested, I'm able to navigate to *ProductPage* and I can see the two tabs, but I can no longer see the native back arrow to go back to *ProductsPage*.

Is it possible to navigate from a single page to tab pages in the same stack? My two tab pages' route would be `//products/product` and `//products/details` so I'm able to navigate back to *ProductsPage* from both end.

Comment: There is no stack created then you navigate to Shell visual hierarchy elements maybe by using `Routing.RegisterRoute();`, this also seems a good start : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1153025/maui-shell-app-back-button

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create the [Register detail page routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0#register-detail-page-routes). These detail pages can then be navigated to using URI-based navigation, from anywhere within the app.

Second, you can check this article about [how to pass the data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0#pass-data) and how to [Process navigation data using query property attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0#process-navigation-data-using-query-property-attributes).

Comment: About your first point, the documentation says "...additional routes can be explicitly registered for any detail pages **that aren't represented in the Shell visual hierarchy**.". Both my tabs have a `ShellContent` so they are represented, aren't they?

About your second point, I know how to pass data between pages, and the question is not about that.